# Printing out values of a dictionary line by line in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following code here:

```
tel = {2: [[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]], 3: [[1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1]]}

for i in tel.values():
    a = ''.join(map(str,i)) 

    print a
```

The dictionary `tel` consists of keys which are the number of 1s in the keys value(here, they are lists of binary). The key's value/s can have more than one (in this case they are)

What this does is print the values that belong to each key line by line.

My goal:

I want to print the string version of each value.

In the example above, I want the output to be:

```
0011
0101
1011
1011
1000
1011
1011
```

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: You don't mention your version of Python -- you should use `itervalues` for this on Python 2 (as in my answer) but `values` on Python 3 does the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> for x in tel.values():
...     for y in x:
...             print ''.join(str(z) for z in y)
... 
0011
0101
1011
1011
1000
1011
1011
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
for key in tel:
    for num in tel[key]:
        print ''.join(str(n) for n in num)
```

For your example this prints:

```
0011
0101
1011
1011
1000
1011
1011
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a generator expression to traverse the data structure, and then just print its content.

```
val_gen = (''.join(map(str,v)) for vs in tel.values() for v in vs)

for v in val_gen:   # Or sorted(val_gen) if order matters.
    print v
```

Comment: `sorted(val_gen)` would sort by the values, not by the keys, which may or may not be what he wants.